# Custom webpart (spfx) not listed in app gallery

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, spfx-webparts

I created an app catalog and a developer site

Then I uploaded the SpFX Webpart package
[image]

But the Webpart is not listed in the app gallery of my developer site so I can't use the web part.
[image]

Any tips?

Comment: What is file extension ?

Comment: file extension is *.sppkg

Comment: Go to “apps for sharepoint” in app catalog and change the view to “unavailable apps”. There you can see if the app deployment has any issue.

Comment: the list of unavailable apps is empty

Comment: Cellist.. I've same issue, can you please help. I've installed Feature Pack 2 and developed simple "HelloworldwebPart". I created two sites in my WebApp Example : Team Site : https://<Domain>/Sites/Test App Catalog : https://<Domain>/Apps/Catalogs Upload the SPFx webpart to App catalog site -- no error and issue. Didn't see apps when I try to add the Webpart to main site (https://<Domain>/Sites/Test >> Site content >> Add an apps). Any Suggestions please ?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in [Microsoft docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/tenant-scoped-deployment):
**Client-side web part visibility in SharePoint sites**
Web parts included in solutions which have been centrally deployed, will be immediately visible in the web part picker in both classic and modern pages.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the solution, you need to use the following command in your console before create the solution.

```
gulp bundle
```

then **create your solution again** and **reinstall it in app catalog**.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on SharePoint Online from the user I was trying to install the APP was not site collection administrator. When I made that specific user a site collection administrator then it allowed and showed the uploaded spfx package in apps